# extracting a structure from a nested structure in c

Tags: c, nested, structure, extract

I have following problem:

I have one global structure that has many structures inside.
Now I want one of the substructures taken out and stored in some other structure.

```
typedef struct 
{
  int a;
}A;

typedef struct
{
 int b;
}B;

typedef struct 
{ 
 A dummy1;
 B dummy2;
} C;
```

I want to declare fourth structure that extracts A from C. 
I did my memcpy, is it only way?

Help will be very appreciated

Thanks 
Huzaifa

Answer (score 1):

You can assign structures.  So:

```
typedef struct
{
    A blah1;
    B blah2;
    /* Other members here */
} D;

C c;
D d;
...
d.blah1 = c.dummy1;
```

is totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointer to the struct you need:

```
int main() {
C c;
c.dummy1.a = 10;
c.dummy2.b = 20;

A *a;

a = &c.dummy1;

printf("%d\n", a->a);

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Should just be able to grab the reference of dummy1.

```
typedef struct { A dummy1; } D;

C var1;
D var2.dummy;
(*var2.dummy) = &var1.dummy1;
```

Comment: It is throwing compilation error.
'dummy' : is not a member of 'D' for (
(*var2.dummy) = &var1.dummy1;)
syntax error : missing ';' before '.' for ( D var2.dummy;)

Comment: there are no references in C. `&` is address-of operator